# How expensive is atmosphere connection?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, atmosphere

I use Atmosphere in my web Java project. I wondering if should I save connections? I would like to open new socket for every conmponent (chat, messages, some games, information etc.). Is it good idea?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it depends on scale: 2-3 connections is probably fine, dozen might be a problem.

You should keep in mind a couple of things though:

1. User may open multiple tabs with same address, so connections probably will be duplicated.
2. Not all users have modern web browser that supports websockets. Atmosphere will degrade gracefully, but at the cost of efficiency. Worst case scenario: no websockets, no streaming, no long-polling, just ajax request every couple of seconds. If there will be 10 "connections", that would be 10 ajax requests every couple of seconds.
3. Also see [Preventing Out Of Memory](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/wiki/Understanding-Broadcaster#preventing-out-of-memory)
4. You can differentiate components in messages and wrap it in some api.

   ```
   request.onMessage = function (response) {
       if (response.component=='chat') {
           listener.onChatMessage(response);
       } else if (response.component=='info'){
           listener.onInfoMessage(info);
       }
   };
   ```